# How to compare the contents of two string objects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-comparison

In PowerShell I have an array of string objects, and I have an object that contains string objects. In Java you can do a `.equals(aObject)` to test if the string values match, whereas doing a `==` test if the two objects refer to the same location in memory.

How do I run an equivalent `.equals(aObject)` in powershell?

I'm doing this:

```
$arrayOfStrings[0].Title -matches $myObject.item(0).Title
```

These both have the exact same string values, but I get a return value of false. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You want to do `$arrayOfString[0].Title -eq $myPbiject.item(0).Title`

`-match` is for regex matching ( the second argument is a regex )

Comment: Casting to string worked best for me: `$a = cat ./text.txt` `$b = cat ./text2.txt` `[string]$a -eq [string]$b` returns false because the files are different

Answer (score 68):

You can do it in two different ways.

Option 1: The `-eq` operator

```
>$a = "is"
>$b = "fission"
>$c = "is"
>$a -eq $c
True
>$a -eq $b
False
```

Option 2: The `.Equals()` method of the `string` object. Because strings in PowerShell are .Net `System.String` objects, any method of that object can be called directly.

```
>$a.equals($b)
False
>$a.equals($c)
True
>$a|get-member -membertype method
```

List of `System.String` methods follows.