# powershell filter where object and return exact match

Tags: powershell, match, where-clause

I have $variables and $Array1

$Array1 contains:

```
FirstName  LastName   ZipCode                          Race

Alice      Jones      {90011, 90017, 90006}            American Indian, Asian, Hispanic 
Allen      Rogers     {90025, 90001}                   African American, American
John       Smith      {90001}                          American
Bob        Wilson     {90025, 90001, 90055, 90084}     African American, American,...
Barbara    Hall       {90025}                          White
```

I want to loop through $Array1 and check if $Variable is in ZipCode.
If it matches then do some stuffs.

What I have is

```
foreach ($variable in $Variables) {
    $result=$Array1 | Where {$_.ZipCode -match "$variable$"}
}
```

For some reason it returns

```
Allen      Rogers     {90025, 90001}                   African American, American
John       Smith      {90001}                          American 
Bob        Wilson     {90025, 90001, 90055, 90084}     African American, American,...
```

I want the **exact match**.
Output should be:

```
John       Smith      {90001}                          American
```

I tried regex like

```
$_.ZipCode -match "^$variable$"
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare the contents of two string objects in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772063/how-to-compare-the-contents-of-two-string-objects-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using the `-ceq` for an **exact** match.  This is also a case-sensitive match.  `-match`/`-cmatch` uses regex to match patterns

A better comparison operator to use, however, would be `-contains`.

```
Where-Object { $_.ZipCode -contains "$variable" }
```

Make sure both comparisons match type.  If your array uses `[Int]`, make sure you're comparing to an `[Int]` object.  This can further be simplified in PSv3+:

```
? ZipCode -contains $variable
```

---

Edit for OP:

```
| Where-Object { ($_.ZipCode.Count -eq 1) -and ($_.ZipCode -eq $variable) }
```

Comment: 90001 is in all three lines. So contains also returns all three results. I only want a result with only 90001, not an array that contains 90001.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want.  It will filter the objects you pass it based on the comparison, so at the end of the pipeline, you end up with the objects that have your $variable in the zip codes.  So you want results where there is only one zip code, and it is the $variable?

Comment: | Where-Object { ($_.ZipCode.Count -eq 1) -and ($_.ZipCode -eq $variable) } is what made it work. Thanks!

Comment: What is `-match` then?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify

```
$_.ZipCode -match "^$variable$"
```

to

```
$_.ZipCode -match ("^"+$variable+"$")
```

which will evaluate the regex as you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.